# How to retopologize low poly object with a few detailed points?

Tags: modeling, topology

How should a low poly object with a few detailed points (the orange areas) like the one below be retopologized? How can the extra detail be added while keeping it low poly and as evenly distributed as possible. Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just my suggestion ;). With this kind of topology you'll be able to crease edges. And it's a bit less messy than yours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Gonzou! I'm completely new to topology this is my first attempt so I'm trying to learn everything I can. ^_^ I really appreciate the help!